# Get Unique Column and Count from CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV File called Products.csv

```
Product_ID,Category
1,A
2,A
3,A
4,B
```

I want a powershell script that will show me the Unique Categories along with the Count and export to CSV.

i.e.

```
A,3
B,1
```

I have used the following code to extract the Unique Categories, but cannot get the Count:

```
Import-Csv Products.csv -DeLimiter ","|
Select 'Category' -Unique |
Export-Csv Summary.csv -DeLimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by count? The count of whats listed in your return?

Comment: please look at the `Group-Object` cmdlet. it can group things by any given combo of properties - even calculated properties. the result will include the count for the matched items. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1) to get the count.

```
Import-Csv Products.csv -DeLimiter "," |
    Group-Object Category | Foreach-Object {
        "{0},{1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Count 
    }
```

If you want a CSV output of the count, you need headers for your data. `Group-Object` outputs property `Name` which is the grouped property value and `Count` which is the number of items in that group.

```
Import-Csv Products.csv -DeLimiter "," |
    Group-Object Category | Select-Object Name,Count |
        Export-Csv Summary.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoType
```

You can take the above code a step further and use [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1)'s calculated properties. Then you can create custom named columns and/or values with expressions.

```
Import-Csv Products.csv -DeLimiter "," |
    Group-Object Category |
        Select-Object @{n='Product_ID';e={$_.Name}},Count |
            Export-Csv Summary.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoType
```