# Creating SKU table pr company name in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

This is like the next step from another question ive asked here before. where i asked [how to count and group skus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542032/count-sku-pr-companyname-in-tenant-with-multiple-companynames-powershell).

Now im trying to create a table ***pr*** Companyname. if i run the command in the 2nd foreach loop. (command below) it fails.

```
$Report | Where-Object Companyname -like "NameGoesHere" | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKUName' ; expression = { ($_.Group.SKUName) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
```

this returns something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
skus for CompanyNameHere

Count Name                                 SKUName                                                                             
----- ----                                 -------                                                                             
    2 c5928f49-12ba-48f7-ada3-0d743a3601d5 VISIOCLIENT, VISIOCLIENT                                                            
   10 b126b073-72db-4a9d-87a4-b17afe41d4ab MDATP_XPLAT, MDATP_XPLAT, MDATP_XPLAT, MDATP_XPLAT, MDATP_XPLAT, MDATP_XPLAT, MDA...
    4 f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d FLOW_FREE, FLOW_FREE, FLOW_FREE, FLOW_FREE                                          
   10 cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46 SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB, SPB
```

however when i try to do this in a loop, that iterates a table with the companynames in it. it fails. I think i might be close, but that i also might be going about this the wrong way.

any tips?

**The whole script is below.**

```
cls
$Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
$Skus = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select Sku*, ConsumedUnits 
ForEach ($Sku in $Skus) {
    Write-Host "Processing license holders for" $Sku.SkuPartNumber
    $SkuUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True | ? { $_.AssignedLicenses -Match $Sku.SkuId }
    ForEach ($User in $SkuUsers) {
        $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
            User        = $User.DisplayName 
            UPN         = $User.UserPrincipalName
            Companyname = $User.Companyname
            Country     = $User.Country
            SKU         = $Sku.SkuId
            SKUName     = $Sku.SkuPartNumber
        }
        $Report.Add($ReportLine) 
    }
}

#Gathers all companynames into a table
$Company = $Report | Select-Object Companyname -Unique | Format-Table

#old alternative that took too long to load
#Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object -Property CompanyName -Unique | Format-table


# Goal: to create one table pr companyname with what skus they have and how many of each they have

Foreach ($F in $Company) {
    write-host "----------------------------------------------------" 
    write-host "SKU's for $F" 
    $Report | Where-Object Companyname -like $($F.Companyname) | Group-Object -Property SKU | Select-Object Count, Name, @{Name = 'SKUName' ; expression = { ($_.Group.SKUName) -join ', ' } } | Format-Table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the Format-Table from this line

```
$Company = $Report | Select-Object Companyname -Unique #| Format-Table
```

When you use Format-Table and save the output to an object you're actually modifying the object with formatting data

```
# No Output
Get-ChildItem | format-table | % { $_.fullname }

# Lists files as expected
Get-ChildItem | % { $_.fullname }
```

If you do the following you can see why:

```
(get-ChildItem)[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo

 (get-ChildItem | ft)[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    FormatStartData                          Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.StartData
```

Another thing I noticed within your script that you could modify to make it slightly quicker.

You are currently looking up *all* users in AzureAD for each SKU. If you move this to one query at the beginning you can filter on that each time.

```
$Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
$Skus = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select-Object Sku*, ConsumedUnits

# Retrieve all users only once rather than within the below foreach loop
# Previously you were looking up every user in AzureAD for each SKU
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $True

ForEach ($Sku in $Skus) {
    Write-Host "Processing license holders for" $Sku.SkuPartNumber
    $SkuUsers = $allUsers | Where-Object { $_.AssignedLicenses -Match $Sku.SkuId }
    ForEach ($User in $SkuUsers) {
        $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
            User        = $User.DisplayName 
            UPN         = $User.UserPrincipalName
            Companyname = $User.Companyname
            Country     = $User.Country
            SKU         = $Sku.SkuId
            SKUName     = $Sku.SkuPartNumber
        }
        $Report.Add($ReportLine) 
    }
}
```

Comment: if i remove the ```format-table```, i get outputs like ``` skus for  @{Companyname=Company01}```

so i dont really get the information i need there